# jQuery if div id contains number from array... do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of numbers which I need to target on pages like this:

```
sku = [1243,3453,6453, ..... ]
```

These values are inside a div on a page like this:

```
  <div id="product_1243">
<div class="block">
test
</div>
 </div>

 <div id="product_3453"> 
<div class="block">
test
</div>
</div>

 <div id="product_6453">
<div class="block">
test
</div>
 </div>
```

I have created a function to check if a number from the array exists in this div:

```
     sku.forEach(function (element) {
            if ($("div[id*='product_item_code_" + element +"']").length) {
                alert("this exists" + element);
            }
        });
```

This works, but I want to ask two questions:

1) How to use insertAfter below to insert some HTML after each `<div class="block">`. It should only get inserted if the statement is true of course.

```
 $("<p>test!</p>").insertAfter(....);
```

2) if this is best for performance because my array is actually much much bigger with over 1000 values to check for in the forEach.

Thanks

Comment: after class block or inside class block?

Comment: @plonknimbuzz after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `append` or `appendTo` if `block` is the only child of `product_***`

```
var $el = $("div[id*='product_item_code_" + element +"']");
if ( $el.length) {
    alert("this exists" + element);
    $("<p>test!</p>").appendTo( $el );
}
```

or

```
var $el = $("div[id*='product_item_code_" + element +"']");
if ( $el.length) {
    alert("this exists" + element);
    $el.append( "<p>test!</p>" )
}
```

In case `block` is not the only child

```
var $el = $("div[id*='product_item_code_" + element +"']");
if ( $el.length) {
    alert("this exists" + element);
    $("<p>test!</p>").insertAfter( $el.find( ".block" ) );
}
```

Comment: block is not the only child.

Comment: if the parent is `$("div[id*='product_item_code_" + element +"']")` then `$(element).find()` will not give what you would expect

Comment: @N.Ivanov you are right, I was mistaken that element is an actual element.

Comment: thanks @gurvinder372 , it's good now.. also is this the best way to do it with a huge array?

Comment: @Zayn how huge? In any case, I think this is quite ok.

Comment: 1000 is not enough to be worried about, if the number of products are far lesser since it will keep iterating `sku` array even when all of them have been processed. Still not a huge number to be worried about.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Store `products` instead of querying it each time as it affects performance.

```
const products = $('div[id^=product_item_code]')
products.each((index, element) => {
    if(sku.includes(element.id.split('_')[1]))
        $('.block', element).after('<p>test!</p>')
})
```